# Swift - What is a good design decision for navigating through multiple scenes not using Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to avoid using tab bar controller because it seems restrictive in where you can place your buttons to move on to another view/scene.

What I was looking for:

For example there is 4 scenes/views: A, B, C, D.

All the 4 scenes have 3 buttons so that

From scene A you can go to scene B or scene C or scene D. (When you click the appropriate button)

From scene B you can go to scene A or scene C or scene D.

From scene C you can go to scene A or scene B or scene D.

From scene D you can go to scene A or scene B or scene C.

I really wanted to avoid having 12 segues.

The container view seems like it could be useful for what I'm doing, but I really wasn't able to find documentation for it.

I tried putting the 4 buttons that navigate to A B C and D in a container, and have the 4 scenes/views embed that container.  But I was also worried about performance because I am not popping the current view controller or popping to root view controller.

Is there a proper way to do this?  I'm relatively new to swift so the answer might be simple.

Comment: You may find the tab bar controller restrictive, but it's also common and easily recognized for what the user can expect.

Comment: Putting 4 buttons at the bottom of a container view is basically creating your own tab bar controlller, if you want the buttons somewhere else then there is no problem doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a rear view with all the pages, instead of a tab bar. I know it is not with buttons like you said, but it is how a lot of people have been doing.

https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Answer (score 0):

As @Rodrigo Guimaraes stated a sidebar menu is a good choice, i've used it in projects.  You could also think about using a [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller).  PageViewControllers are used to display an array of ViewController's views.  Then you will just need to set your UIButtons to navigate to the A, B, C, D viewcontroller in your pageview controller.  This will also give your user the ability to swap from a->b->c->d and back again, Like turning the pages of a book or magazine.